# Description of a sub-taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, description

I am using this code to display description of a taxonomy.

```
<?php $my_taxonomy = 'institute'; $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $my_taxonomy ); echo term_description($terms[0]->term_id, $my_taxonomy); ?>
```

What to do if I want to show description of sub or even sub-taxonomy?

Comment: Btw, does `term_description` work with custom taxonomies? The codex doesn't say so and I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Term description works only with term id and the taxonomy name, so if you want to get the sub term's description, you should first get all the children of a term(and their children, if its another level deep) and loop over their ids with a single `term_description` call per id.

```
<?php 
    $my_taxonomy = 'institute';
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $my_taxonomy );
    echo term_description($terms[0]->term_id, $my_taxonomy);

    //Assuming you have only 1 parent term, if multiple then loop over the $terms array
    $term_children = get_term_children( $terms[0]->term_id, $my_taxonomy );

    foreach($term_children as $term_child)
    {
        echo term_description($term_child->term_id, $my_taxonomy).'<br />';
    }
?>
```

This should give you an idea.